# Geometry RMO-INMO LEVEL, based on pedal triangles

Tags: geometry

$P$ is the point in Triangle $ABC$. Let $XYZ$ be the pedal triangle of point $P$ with respect to $ABC, QRT$ be the pedal triangle of point $P$ with respect to $XYZ$ and $LMN$ be the pedal triangle of point $P$ with respect to $QRT$. Prove that $ABC$ is similar to $LMN$.

My idea was to use angle chasing or circumcircle properties but got stuck everywhere.
Thanks!!

Comment: Might want to check out http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa2014/Vereen/Exploration%209

Comment: thankss for the help!!